# Typescript doesn't care what I put in my interface and doesn't seems to understand my implementation and imports for redux-toolkit & styled components

Tags: typescript, next.js, styled-components, redux-toolkit, aws-cloud9

### My Issue:

Typescript seems to be throwing errors on the wrong things. It doesn't seem to care if the interface in my *index.tsx* file doesn't match the object it is supposed to describe. At the same time it:

1. Gives me an error when trying to import a Type from redux-toolkit.

   [image: See screenshot of the import WITHOUT the type keyword here.]

   [image: See screenshot of the import WITH the type keyword here.]
2. Gives type error on my store object but the redux docs say shouldn't have any type problems with that.

   [image: See screenshot here.]
3. Using an example from the styled components docs: claims my traversal of my theme object does not match my DefaultTheme interface even though it clearly does.
   [image: See screenshot here.]

### What I have tried:

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Typescript and all the libraries it complains about the implementations of and well as trying different guides on how to implement them and TypeScript but nothing has helped.

### Tools to reproduce:

Here is a link to the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/alec-horwitz/testNextSite) containing my troubled code. It points to a local host API that I will not share because I am not permitted to (let's leave it at that). So if you decide to run the code I recommend either replacing the fetch with mock data or removing all code relating to it. To start the project it should be as simple as running `npm install` and then `npm run dev` and then in a separate terminal for the typescript compiler run `tsc -w`.

Please note: I'm running this code base on an AWS Cloud9 instance using Ubuntu Server. I bring this up because I'm not sure if the virtualized environment might have something to do with these problems I am having.

**Steps I took to write this code from the ground up:**

To initialize my project I ran the command: `npx create-next-app --ts --example with-styled-components testNextSite`

After I ran that command I then proceeded to add redux to my project following this [YouTube guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ss-_S1Vyxa0).

Lastly I added some basic examples to show how useEffect, useState, and redux can be used. I didn't notice the issues with TypeScript until I tried adding some typescript examples which lead to me writing this Stack Overflow post... and now you're all caught up.

### Personal notes:

While I have technically spent a year writing typescript code for work; I have only ever written basic interfaces and have never setup or configured typescript myself before. I have even less expertise with NextJs and AWS Cloud9. So I am hoping this problem is a simple fix for someone better versed in the technologies in use here.

Please let me know if there is anything I can do to improve my question. Thank you in advance for any and all help with this issue I'm having.

### **UPDATE:**

Just spoke to AWS's customer support... Turns out there is no way to solve this problem on AWS's Cloud9 as of 10-19-2022. They are using very outdated TypeScript definitions and have absolutely no idea if or when this will be fixed. They also don't provide a way to change the definitions manually on the users end. So if you want to use typescript on AWS's Cloud9, don't. It doesn't work properly.

Comment: Your first error looks like either your TypeScript version is out of date, or your editor's TypeScript version is out of date, or your editor is just being a silly goose.

Comment: Well, my TypeScript version is the latest stable release. Are you saying there's another setting I need to play with? If so what and how?

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be a problem with your editor setup, if you [open the repo on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/alec-horwitz/testNextSite?file=/slices/testSlice.ts) those imports work just fine.

Comment: Any suggestions on what I could try changing about my editor setup? As I mentioned I'm not particularly well versed in AWS Cloud9 or TypeScript. So I could use some pointers on how I could try changing things

Comment: I have no experience with AWS Cloud9, I'm sorry. It seems like it is running on an outdated TS version or is generally not configured for TypeScript.